# opencart 2.0 Confirm order button missing

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have use code from following [websit](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-in-opencart-part-3--cms-22464) in Open cart 2.0.

I have set admin side successful but in form it does not show me button to confirm order. please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain more what is in your admin side payment form ?

- do your payment method has status input type in admin side, you can see this in all other payment method and **it's name should be payment_method_name_status like here custompayment_status** if payment method don't have this then OC will not display it.

  ```
      if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
  ```

OC checks this condition in Payment controller at front side and only display enabled payment method.

[image: it's Paypal Pro]

I think it's the problem else OC will display some some kind of error, would not just hide your method.

If it's not case then condition can be total order amount etc if you added in your method, i can't tell without seeing that.